# How to put an image resized with Pillow into GridFS?

Tags: python-2.7, gridfs, python-imaging-library

**Scenario**

I use a formData form to upload an image via ajax which is then added to a MongoDB GridFS database.

This was working:

```
my_image = request.files.my_image
raw = my_image.file.read()
fs.put(raw)
```

**Desired Behaviour**

I want to resize the image with [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) before adding to GridFS.

**What I Tried**

I changed the above to:

```
my_image = request.files.my_image
raw = Image.open(my_image.file.read())
raw_resized = raw.resize((new_dimensions))
fs.put(raw_resized)
```

**Actual Behaviour**

I am now getting 500 errors. Tail shows:

```
TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str
```

**Question**

How do I properly handle the Pillow image object so that I can add it to GridFS?

**Troubelshooting**

This is still unresolved, but I'm just adding my attempts to understand what is happening with file types etc at different stages of the process by using the interpretor:

```
>>> my_image = open("my_great_image.jpg")
>>> my_image
<open file 'my_great_image.jpg', mode 'r' at 0x0259CF40>
>>> type(my_image)
<type 'file'>
>>> my_image_read = my_image.read()
>>> my_image_read
# lots of image data
>>> type(my_image_read)
<type 'str'>
>>> my_pil_image = Image.open("my_great_image.jpg")
>>> my_pil_image
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=400x267 at 0x2760CD8>
>>> type(my_pil_image)
<type 'instance'>
```

So from this I think I can deduce that, originally, GridFS was accepting of the string version of the image generated from the `read()` method.

So I think I need to somehow make the Pillow image object a string in order to get it into GridFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Wo, check this out, it works, the logic is:

1. Form uploads image,
2. Pillow does three different resizes,
3. Use StringIO to convert Pillow objects to strings
4. Put resized images, as strings, in GridFS.

**Python**

```
from PIL import Image
import StringIO

# define three new image sizes
card_dimensions = (108,108)
main_dimensions = (42,38)
thumb_dimensions = (18,14)
# covert uploaded image to Pillow object
raw_pil = Image.open(my_image.file)
# conversion to card size
raw_card_output = StringIO.StringIO()
raw_card = raw_pil.resize((card_dimensions))
raw_card.save(raw_card_output,format=raw_pil.format)
raw_card_output_contents = raw_card_output.getvalue()
# conversion to main size
raw_main_output = StringIO.StringIO()
raw_main = raw_pil.resize((main_dimensions))
raw_main.save(raw_main_output,format=raw_pil.format)
raw_main_output_contents = raw_main_output.getvalue()
#conversion to thumb size
raw_thumb_output = StringIO.StringIO()
raw_thumb = raw_pil.resize((thumb_dimensions))
raw_thumb.save(raw_thumb_output,format=raw_pil.format)
raw_thumb_output_contents = raw_thumb_output.getvalue()
# put card image into GridFS
fs.put(raw_card_output_contents)
# put main image into GridFS
fs.put(raw_main_output_contents)
# put thumb image into GridFS
fs.put(raw_thumb_output_contents)
```

**Further Explanation**

Basically I deduced that GridFS was accepting a string, so therefore I needed to transform the Pillow object into a string.

The interpreter troubleshooting below should make some of the dynamics clearer and carries on from the troubleshooting in the original post:

```
>>> my_pil_image
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=400x267 at 0x2760CD8>
>>> my_pil_image_resized = my_pil_image.resize((50,50))
>>> my_pil_image_resized
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=50x50 at 0x2898710>
>>> output = StringIO.StringIO()
>>> my_pil_image_resized.save(output,format="JPEG")
>>> contents = output.getvalue()
>>> type(contents)
<type 'str'>
>>> contents
# lots of image data
```

So basically the above process show the mechanics of how to convert the Pillow object into a string which can then be added to GridFS.

Answer (score 0):

I just got a simple way to do this with flask.

I am using FileStorage for file holder before uploading to gridFS.
It also help me to wrap image from pillow after resize.

Document looks like this.

```
from mongoengine import Document ImageField


class SomeDocument(Document):
    icon = ImageField(required=False, collection_name="collection_name")
```

And the controller is

```
from io import BytesIO
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(request.files.get('icon'))
im.thumbnail((400, 400))

output = BytesIO()

im.save(output, format=im.format, quality=90)

original_extension = request.files.get('icon').filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower()

SomeDocument.icon.put(FileStorage(output, content_type=f"image/{original_extension"))
SomeDocument.save()
im.close()
```